# DoubleClick Floodlight Tags: Expected URL match required?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-floodlight

In setting up Floodlight tags for a site that is already running a content experiments through Google Analytics, do I need to establish a separate Floodlight Activity for each variation page URL?

There are a few different pages (landing-a, landing-b), each with 1-3 test URLs (-1, -2) leading to a separate thank-you sub page. My thought is to create a single floodlight activity for each group of pages and apply it to all of the thank you pages via Google Tag Manger.

Example:

```
/landing-a-1 control URL
/landing-a-2 test URL
/landing-a-1/thanks - conversion page for control URL
/landing-a-2/thanks - conversion page for test URL
/landing-b-1 control URL
/landing-b-2 test URL
/landing-b-1/thanks - conversion page for control URL
/landing-b-2/thanks - conversion page for test URL
```

My concern is the "Expected URL" field. According to the [Implementation guide checklist](https://support.google.com/ds/checklist/6079619?hl=en) this field should be the page where the tag will be placed, but it isn't clear what happens when the tag is placed on a page with a similar URL. Example: Expected URL set as /landing-a-1/thanks, but same tag placed on landing-a-2/thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a definite answer from Google (I have the same question) but did find a marketing company [claiming it doesn't matter](http://support.freespee.com/hc/en-us/articles/201533971-DoubleClick-app-activation).

I'm running on that hypothesis – if I discover differently I'll update here.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. In the absence of responses i went with a single Floodlight Activity for each landing page and it seemed to work fine. I'm not sure if there is an advantage to having separate activities when running the landing page test through DoubleClick, but I haven't noticed issues yet.